# MVC Routing 404 Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a .Net 4.0 MVC 4.0 project. I am getting following two errors  multiple times in my log table.

1. `404_System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The controller for path '/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive' was not found or does not implement IController.`
2. `404_System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The controller for path '/UpdateAccrual' was not found or does not implement IController.`

Following is my Global.Asax file.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              var error = Server.GetLastError();
              RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
              routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
              routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index");
              string logDescription = Convert.ToString(error);
              var errorCode = (error is HttpException) ? (error as HttpException).GetHttpCode() : 0;
              if (errorCode != 0)
              {
                  logDescription = errorCode + "_"+logDescription;
              }
              ErrorLogBL.InsertLog(1, 1, UIConstants.LogName, logDescription, AppContext.CurrentUser.EffectiveUserID);
              IController errorController = new ErrorController();
              errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
              Response.End();

        }
```

Note: There is a UpdateAccrual controller.

Note: I don't mind the unobtrusive error. But the UpdateAccrual controller is causing the system to navigate to error view.

**QUESTION**

1. Is it due to any misuse of `Response.End()`
2. Or is it due to any issue in the `routing`?

Comment: The obvious question... Do you *have* these URLs in your application?  `/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive` looks like it's missing a `.js` on the end.  Is `UpdateAccrual` a controller?  What should that URL do?

Comment: @David There is a UpdateAccrual controller. It has a index view that will show textboxes where users can post values.

Comment: Is UpdateAccrual controller deriving from Controller?

Comment: do you have the index action set as default?